# SQL Automatically Generating Date Range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server called `[dbo].[Worth_Weekly_Report]`. This report usually runs on every Tuesday (12/05/2017), and it generates records of transactions performed in the past week(11/27/2017 to 12/03/2017 This means Monday to Sunday, and the current query allows me to manually input the date before it runs.

Query:

```
DECLARE @end_date DATE,
        @begin_date DATE

SET @begin_date = '11/20/2017'
SET @end_date = '11/26/2017'

IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_Table_1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Temp_Table_1         

--The other parts of the query are meaningless.
```

So my plan is to automate this query by connecting it to excel, and the query will automatically generate a new date range (e.g. 12/04/2017 to 12/10/2017) every week.

This is what I wrote for that purpose, but it seems not be working:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Worth_Weekly_Report]
    DECLARE
        @end_date DATE = '11/27/2017',     --Report start date---
        @begin_date DATE = '12/31/2018'    --Report end date

    SET @begin_date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @begin_date)
    SET @end_date = DATEADD(DAY, +7, @end_date)
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_Table_1') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE Temp_Table_1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can use [`DatePart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) to get the current `weekday` and use that to adjust the current date to the appropriate start date, then add 6 days to get the end date. Note that you should take [`@@DateFirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql) into account. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Noted. I use a Ms-Sql-Server

Comment: Be careful with date strings. Those literals can produce incorrect dates or errors based on your preferences. It is better to use the ANSI standard YYYYMMDD which will always produce the same date.

Comment: @alexedeigba unless I misunderstood you simply want the range for last week given a date you pass in. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your procedure should start like the following

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Worth_Weekly_Report]
@begin_date DATE

AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @end_date DATE

    SET @begin_date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @begin_date)
    SET @end_date = DATEADD(DAY, +7, @begin_date)
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_Table_1') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE Temp_Table_1
```

Comment: OK. i noticed you changed the query to CREATE instead of ALTER. I have created the Stored Procedure already, and will only want to alter it anytime i run the stored procedure. So i went ahead and changed it to ALTER and ran it the stored procedure again, and i got this error message.

Comment: " Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Worth_Weekly_Report, Line 322
Incorrect syntax near 'END'."

Comment: @alexedeigba can you show the whole stored procedure

Comment: I tried but the query is too long that's why i didn't attach.

Comment: @alexedeigba what i did,is to make @begin_date a procedure parameter which will be passed when executing. and that will is more recommended then altering procedure each time you want to execute it. By example `EXEC [dbo].[Worth_Weekly_Report] '20170112'`

Answer (score 0):

You can just set it statically with built in functions. Regardless of when you run this, it will run for the previous week...

```
DECLARE
     @begin_date DATE = cast(dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) as date)
    ,@end_date DATE = cast(dateadd(day,6,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)) as date)

select @begin_date, @end_date
```

Or, if you want to pass in a date and run it for the week prior to that date, you can do that too...

```
DECLARE @someDateYouPassIn date = '20170419'
DECLARE
     @begin_date DATE = cast(dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, @someDateYouPassIn) - 1, 0) as date)
    ,@end_date DATE = cast(dateadd(day,6,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, @someDateYouPassIn) - 1, 0)) as date)

select @begin_date, @end_date
```